# How to hide multiple elements and display only one item from each container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide all span elements and display just one from its parent container(coin).
The output of what I want to achieve should display just "1" and "first" while the others will be hidden.

```
<div class="types" >
<div class="coin">
    <span class="num">1</span>
    <span class="num">2</span>
    <span class="num">3</span>
</div>
<div class="coin">
    <span class="num">first</span>
    <span class="num">second</span>
    <span class="num">third</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you attempted? What didn't work for you? Remember that SO is for helping you to debug code, not to write it for you. Also note that this can be achieved with a single line in CSS, no JS requird.

Comment: You can do it using CSS ```.num:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in Jquery. You can do like below with `each()` and access the first child with `children()` and `first()`.

```js
$(".coin").each(function () {
  $(this).children().first().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="types">
  <div class="coin">
    <span class="num">1</span>
    <span class="num">2</span>
    <span class="num">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="coin">
    <span class="num">first</span>
    <span class="num">second</span>
    <span class="num">third</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I needed, you're doing well. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

What about doing it with pure css?

```css
.num:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="types">
  <div class="coin">
    <span class="num">1</span>
    <span class="num">2</span>
    <span class="num">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="coin">
    <span class="num">first</span>
    <span class="num">second</span>
    <span class="num">third</span>
  </div>
</div>
```